# What does nowait mean in RabbitMQ's exchange.declare()?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Pretty straightforward question.  I can't find it in the docs or the spec.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [AMQP spec](http://www.amqp.org/specification/0-9-1/amqp-org-download), section 1.1:

> If set, the server will not respond to the method. The client should not wait for a reply method. If the
>   server could not complete the method it will raise a channel or connection exception.